# ReferenceError: Discord is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to make some changes in this discord bot script.But to be honest I don't know anything about javascript.So this is the error I am getting.

**Error:**

client = new Client();

ReferenceError: Client is not defined

**And here this is my code:**

````
    require('discord.js'),
      client = new Discord.Client();
    
    
    client.once('ready',
        () => console.info('Bot started.')
    );
    client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (Old, New) => {
        if(New.user.bot) return;
        if(Old.user.bot) return;
    
        if(New.voiceChannelID == process.env.voiceID) {
            New.guild.createChannel(New.user.username, { type: "voice", parent: process.env.categoryID })
                .then((set) => {
                    return New.setVoiceChannel(New.guild.channels.get(set.id));
                });
        }
    
        if(Old.voiceChannel) {
            let filter = (ch) =>
                (ch.parentID == process.env.categoryID)
                && (ch.id !== process.env.voiceID)
                && (Old.voiceChannelID == ch.id)
                && (Old.voiceChannel.members.size == 0);
            
            return Old.guild.channels
                .filter(filter)
                .forEach((ch) => ch.delete());
        }
    });
    
    client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);```
````

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `Discord`, so when you call `new Discord.Client()` you get the error.

In the first line of your code replace `require('discord.js')` with:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

You also need to actually define your `client`, in your second line add the **const** keyword:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to declare Discord

```
const Discord=require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS use CommonJS modules as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Get one of the Discord.js exported modules:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js'); // Client
```

Get the entire Discord.js module:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Discord.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your client..

all you gotta do is at the top add this script:

```
const { client } = new Discord.Client();
```

Comment: A client is already being initialized, no need to deconstruct it